# How can I on browsing Nodes with Milo OPCUA Client, chek the Datatyp

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

Im browsing with Milo OPCUA Client the Nodes:

```
//get my baseNodes
List<ReferenceDescription> references = toList(browseResult.getReferences());

    for (ReferenceDescription rd : references) {

            //check all nodes under Basenodes
            rd.getNodeId().local().ifPresent(nodeId -> browseNode(indent + "  ", client, nodeId));

            if ((rd.getNodeClass().getValue() == 2)){
                    referencesChilds.add(rd);
            }
        }
```

I would like hier to check this Variable, if it ist an Array, then add to my referencesChilds List.

```
if ((rd.getNodeClass().getValue() == 2)){
     referencesChilds.add(rd);
}
```

How can i do it, any Idea, the ReferenceDescription Object have no Method to check the Datatype.

Answer (score 0):

The next step after browsing is typically to call the Read service and read the `DataType`, `ValueRank`, and `ArrayDimensions` attributes for each node.

Comment: Yes, do it :



`ReadValueId readValueId = new ReadValueId(nodeId,
                AttributeId.Value.uid(), null, QualifiedName.NULL_VALUE);`

After this i subscribe the Nodes. But bevor i subscribe, i will check if it is an Array, but i dont know how.